# KNN Decision Boundary

Tags: machine-learning

I have two classes:

```
x={-3,-2,1}  //represented by *
y={0,5,6,7}  //represented by x
```

If k=3, how do you determine the decision boundary?

```
           *    *         x    *                   x    x    x                   
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
-5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Supposedly the correct answer is 1.5, between 1 and 2. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KNN algorithm classifies new observations by looking at the K nearest neighbors, looking at their labels, and assigning the majority (most popular) label to the new observation.

For KNN with K=3, anything < 1.5 will be classified as `*` and anything > 1.5 will be classified as `x`.

You can see this by trying out a few examples. Suppose you need to classify a value of **1**. The three nearest neighbors are the `*` at **1**, the `x` at **0**, and the `*` at **-2**. Since there are two `*`'s and one `x`, **1** will be classified as `*`.

Now suppose you want to classify **2**. Here, the three nearest neighbors are the `x` at **0**, the `*` at **1**, and the `x` at **5**. So **2** would get classified as `x`.

The KNN process implicitly defines a decision boundary. The best way to determine it that I'm aware of is to try a bunch of examples and look for the transition boundary where observation classifications change from one class to another class. In your example this would look like this:

**-5** -> `*`
**-4** ->  `*`
**-3** ->  `*`
**-2** ->  `*`
**-1** ->  `*`
**0**  ->  `*`
**1**  ->  `*`
**2**  ->  `x`
**3**  ->  `x`
**4**  ->  `x`

You can see this in your example - the decision boundary is somewhere between 1 and 2. Hence the 1.5 answer.